# How to parse date from bank statement PDF

Tags: parsing, sed, awk, grep

I'm looking for a way to pull the statement date from various statement PDFs I download.

Using `mdimport -d2` (on a Mac) I can get the Spotlight index metadata for the file, which includes a field called `kMDItemTextContent`, which contains all the text of the PDF.

Now I need to create a set of rules to pull the statement dates from this text, which varies from file to file, and convert it to a standard `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

I'm not sure if I should use `sed` or `grep` or `awk` ... and what arguments to use.

Here are some examples of the *relevant* part of the text and the *desired result*:

`Jan. 23, 2014 31 Days in Billing Cycle` -> *2014-01-23*

`Service period 02/03 - 03/02` -> *2014-03-02*

`Statement Date: February 3, 2014` -> *2014-02-03*

`Statement Closing Date 04/04/2014` -> *2014-04-04*

`Statement Period Jan 6 - Feb 5, 2014` -> *2014-02-05*

Comment: given the data formats vary wildly, you'd be better off matching each one individually, instead of trying to make a frankenregex to try and catch them all.

Comment: Yes, I figured I'd need a separate 'rule' for each one. I'm willing to do that, but which command should I use? Just looking for a starting point.

Comment: sed/awk probably. grep can match for a file, but it's intended for extracting lines of text, not "chunks of lines". not sure what awk and sed's date production/formatting capabilities are, but at elast they can pull out the relevant values so you can feed it to something like `date` for formatting.

Comment: Can you give me one example with sed/awk? At least to pull out just the date portion?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an awk solution for the first pattern; you can use that as the basis for the rest:

```
> echo "Jan. 23, 2014 31 Days in Billing Cycle" |
  awk 'BEGIN { split("Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec",
                     months, "|") }
       /Days in Billing Cycle/ { printf("%d-%02d-%d\n", $3,
                                        months[substr($1,1,3)]+1,
                                        substr($2, 1, length($2)-1)) }'
2014-01-23
```

I'm assuming that the text "Jan. 23, 2014 31 Days in Billing Cycle" appears on a single line by itself (thus, between two newlines).

Comment: Actually the text is NOT on a single line.